# How to add typewriter effect in Davinci Resolve or Fusion?

Tags: davinci-resolve, fusion

I know that Adobe After Effects allows adding typewriter effect to text in videos but how to do the same in Davinci Resolve or Fusion?

Answer (score 3):

In the Text+ tool there is a control for write-on that does exactly what you want. To quote from the [Fusion 9 Tool Reference](http://documents.blackmagicdesign.com/Fusion/20170801-2d196b/Fusion_9_Tool_Reference.pdf):

> Write On 
>   This range control is used to quickly apply simple Write On
>   and Write Off effects to the text. To create a Write On effect,
>   animate the End portion of the control from 1 to 0 over the length of
>   time required. To create a Write Off effect, animate the Start portion
>   of the range control from 0 to 1.

When they say Write-On, unfortunately they don't mean the hand writing effect more commonly called write-on (I got too excited when I first saw it), but rather what you called the "typewriter effect". Video tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/1J4vUYNBI8w?t=1m45s)

Comment: there is also a template on motionarray that you can nab for $30 a month along with thousands of other assets https://motionarray.com/davinci-resolve-templates/typewriter-pro-584810/